# Is deployment.properties used/accessed in OpenJDK 8 releases

Tags: java

I am struggling to verify if deployment.properties is used at all in OpenJDK 8 releases or not, or it is only specific to the Oracle release of the JDK/JRE.

I am on a project that uses OpenJDK 8 releases from https://adoptium.net/, and from the image retrieved, I see none of the components that (Oracle) documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/properties.html) states is used by deployment.properties: Java Plugins, Java Web Start, and Java Control Panel. The project is undergoing a cybersecurity review, and there is a debate if the deployment.properties (based on past Oracle JRE releases) is applicable to OpenJDK, mainly version 8 releases.

Does OpenJDK 8, in any way, check for deployment.properties?  Is there an authoritative source verifying if the answer is "yes" or "no"?

BTW, doing a search for "deployment.properties" on the OpenJDK issue tracking website, https://bugs.openjdk.org/projects/JDK/issues/, provides a lot of hits, including hits for 8 and later releases.  But it is not clear to me if these are really Oracle-specific-release items that happen to be in the database, or they are applicable to core OpenJDK releases.

Comment: Can you link to the Oracle documentation that you mentioned?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/properties.html

Comment: Post such details as edits to your Question rather than as Comments.